# Select an li element in a listbox with Selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have a python script where i'm using Selenium to do some testing.

Currently I am trying to select some elements in multiple list boxes.

You can check out the site here: http://www.guloggratis.dk/annonce/opret (The language is Danish, if you are wondering)

So what I want to do is select a category, then some new categories pops up and I select one of those until there are no more categories left.

I can select the first element in the first box like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.guloggratis.dk/annonce/opret')
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("span.pos-absolute").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("categoryId_597").click()
```

While this works, I don’t know why i need to do

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("span.pos-absolute").click()
```

Anyways if I try select a category from the list that appears in the second box like this

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.guloggratis.dk/annonce/opret')
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("span.pos-absolute").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("categoryId_597").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("categoryId_598”).click()
```

it doesn’t work even though "categoryId_598” is an id of one of the new categories.

I appreciate any help you might provide and I look forward to hear your answer.

If you have a problem reproducing the error, make a comment and I’ll instantly respond from my phone.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I don't get any error message in my script. It just doesn't click. I can include the complete script (50 lines) if it helps. I just tried my code above and it doesn't build out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because of the cookie window?

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.guloggratis.dk/annonce/opret')
browser.find_element_by_id("cookieClose").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("categoryId_597").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("categoryId_598").click()
```

works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks you very much Zaphod, you method solved my issue. I will accept your answer as a solution.